# show/hide dynamic error messages and prevent default

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I've got a simple form to validate and I can't use jQuery validate().

I've made two error messages - one for a checkbox group and one for an email confirmation mismatch.

Here is the form

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>testForm</title>
  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

<body>
  <div class="container main">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 logo">
        <p class="text-center">Use this form to request more information.</p>
        <div class="well">
          <form name="enrol" id="enrol" xmp-register class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group" id="checkboxGroup">
              <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-lg-offset-4 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                <div class="checkbox">
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="flexi" name="checkBoxes"> Yes, email me more information about Scheme 1</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-lg-offset-4 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                <div class="checkbox">
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="kiwi" name="checkBoxes"> Yes, email me more information about Scheme 2</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-lg-offset-4 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                <div class="checkbox">
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="protect" checkBoxes="protect"> Yes, email me more information about Scheme 3</label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="firstName" class="col-md-3 col-lg-4 control-label"> First name </label>
              <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-7">
                <input type="text" name="firstName" maxlength="42" class="form-control" required>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="lastName" class="col-md-3 col-lg-4 control-label"> Last name </label>
              <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-7">
                <input type="text" name="lastName" maxlength="42" class="form-control" required>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="emailGroup">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email" class="col-md-3 col-lg-4 control-label"> Email address </label>
                <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-7">
                  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="confirmEmail" class="col-md-3 col-lg-4 control-label"> Confirm email address </label>
                <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-7">
                  <input type="email" id="confirmEmail" name="confirmEmail" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="contact-number" class="col-md-3 col-lg-4 control-label"> Contact number </label>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" name="contactNumber" class="form-control" pattern="\d+">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                <select name="contactNumberType" class="form-control">
                  <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Type</option>
                  <option value="mobile">Mobile</option>
                  <option value="business-hours">Business Hours</option>
                  <option value="after-hours">After Hours</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="memberNumber" class="col-md-3 col-lg-4 control-label" style="padding-top:0px;"> Member number
                <br>(if you already have one)</label>
              <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-7">
                <input type="number" name="memberNumber" class="form-control">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
                <input id="submitBtn" name="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Complete" class="form-control btn btn-primary">
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <!--[if lte IE 7]>
<script src="https://raw.github.com/mattpowell/localstorageshim/master/localstorageshim.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->

  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  <!-- WM coding -->
  <script src="so.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

and here is the JS

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
// set flags to control error messages
    var emailError = false;
    var selectionError=false;
    $("#submitBtn").click({
    // validation checks performed on submit:
    // 1. check that at least one checkbox is checked
    emailError,selectionError // passing parameters to click function
    }, function (event) {
        var flexibox = document.getElementById("flexi");
        var kiwibox = document.getElementById("kiwi");
        var protectbox = document.getElementById("protect");
        var mainEmail = document.getElementById("email").value;
        var confirmEmail = document.getElementById("confirmEmail").value;

        var noSelection = checkRequest();   // check if selection made
        var emailMismatch = checkEmails(mainEmail, confirmEmail);
        console.log(noSelection);
        if (noSelection || emailMismatch) {    // checks the first element of variable returned
            event.preventDefault();
        }

        function checkRequest() {
            if (protectbox.checked == false && (kiwibox.checked == false && flexibox.checked == false)) { //no option selected
                if (selectionError === false) { // if no error message showing
                    $("#checkboxGroup").after( // add error message
                        '<div id="noSelect" class="col-md-offset-3 col-lg-offset-4 col-md-8 col-lg-8"><p style="color:red;">Please select at least one option.</p></div>'
                    );
                    selectionError = true; //update flag to avoid multiple error messages on repeated submit attempts
                }
                return selectionError;  // exit
            } else {    // something is selected
                $("#noSelect").remove();    // remove error message
                selectionError=false;   //reset flag
                return selectionError;  //exit
            }
        }

        function checkEmails(mainEmail, confirmEmail) {
            if (mainEmail != confirmEmail) { //2. email addresses don't match
            if (emailError === false) { // if no error message showing
                $("#emailGroup").after( // add error message
                    '<div id="emailMismatch" class="col-md-offset-3 col-lg-offset-4 col-md-8 col-lg-8"><p style=color:red;">Please ensure the email addresses match.</p></div>'
                );
                emailError = true; //update flag to avoid multiple error messages on repeated submit attempts
            }
                return true;
            } else if (mainEmail == "" || confirmEmail == "") { // to stop email error message showing when the fields haven't been filled
                return emailError;
            } else {
                return emailError;
            }

        }
    });
});

// force Sarari to honour required attributes
jQuery.getScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webshim/1.15.7/minified/polyfiller.js')     .done(function () {         
    webshims.polyfill('forms');          
});
```

The problem I'm having is that the checkbox group error message hides and shows each time a submit attempt is made - works OK, but the email mismatch error shows once and then can't be removed and the form won't submit, even when an email mismatch has been corrected.

When I inspect the page in Chrome and step through the code, I can see that the two variables for the email check, "mainEmail" and "confirmEmail" do match, but the following statements are skipped as if they do not match.

If anyone could give me some help with this I'd be really grateful. I'm sure that the code is unnecessarily lengthy - I'm pretty much a beginner.

Thanks and regards,

Malcolm

Comment: Sorry - I meant to add that I can't use jQuery validate because the version of jQuery I need for XMPie is 1.10.2.

Comment: JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/malcolmwhild/jqvLtc97/4/ (I hope - haven't used it before)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not unsetting the error message nor setting emailError to false . Change the else block of checkEmail to

```
else {
        emailError = false;
        $("emailMismatch").remove();
        return emailError;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Everything is working now.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted